# How to select and delete multiple objects on Wagtail admin UI?

Tags: django, wagtail

What I wanted should be the so-called **bulk-operations**, i.e. on Django admin, for a Django model there could be many objects created, and we can select multiple of them and delete.

[image]

However, when I registered Django models in Wagtail, the Wagtail admin doesn't show anything similar to Django bulk operations.

And I searched for a while, looks like bulk operations are not supported in Wagtail admin?

Any other alternative we could use for Wagtail?

Answer (score 1):

As of Wagtail 2.9, I don't think it's possible to bulk select pages, but you can do so with snippets.

You can submit a feature request regarding bulk selections in page lists on [GitHub](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues), but search first if such a request already exists before creating a new one.

Comment: I don't want to register my model as snippets, since I don't think my models are snippets in the project, although I could implement it that way. Other than that, no other options?

Comment: That's correct, but it's really up to you how to implement your models.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk actions for ModelAdmin views are unfortunately not yet supported by Wagtail - you can leave a comment [in this issue in Wagtail's repo](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2719) if you want to see it prioritized.